# visual studio 2008 - add excel 2010 workbook

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2008, excel-2010

I have Visual Studio 2008, and will need to an Excel Workbook Project.  The options for Excel 2007 and 2003 Workbook are there.  But everytime I chose any of those it prompts me with an error saying "A compatible version of Microsoft Office is not installed on this computer. ...".  So I checked my office version and sure enough it wasn't 2007 nor 2003, but 2010.

But I don't see any options Excel 2010 Workbook on my Visual Studio, already tried toggling the frameworks .NET 3.5/3.0/2.5 and it's none.  I'm thinking maybe it is on .NET 4.0 so I tried downloading the 4.0 installer on microsoft site, but after the installation, there's still no .NET 4.0 in my VS2008, let alone Excel 2010 Workbook.

Any advice will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've done a lot of work in Excel from VB.net and never found a need for the Excel Workbook Project. You can do what you need to do by adding a reference to Excel and programming against it.

Check out: [Automating Excel](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1346865&seqNum=5)